# Flutter: UI reactions with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

1. *On some event, I want to navigate to another screen with Navigator.*
   I could easily achieve it with BlocListener:

```dart
  BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  bloc: blocA,
  listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is Success) {              
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/details');
      }  
  },
  child: Container(),
)
```

But I can't find the direct equivalent for it in a pure Provider.
The only way I see is to swap screens:

```
home: Consumer<Auth>(
    builder: (_, auth, __) => auth.user == null ? LoginPage() : MainPage()
)
```

It's a common way. But it will not use Navigator, hence it will just 'pop' MainPage without screen transition.

2. *On some event, I want to play some animation in UI.*

I found in the documentation that `Listenable` class is intended for dealing with Animations, but it's not explained in details.

3. *On some event, I want to clear a TextEditingController.*
4. *On some event, I want to show a dialog.*

And more similar tasks...
How to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found a way. I'm not sure if it's the only or the best way, or the way foreseen by Provider's creator, however it works.

The idea is to keep a helper Stream inside of my Store class (I mean business-logic class provided with Provider), and to subscribe to its changes in my widget.

So in my Store class I have:

```dart
  final _eventStream = StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream get eventStream => _eventStream.stream;
  
  void dispose() {
    _eventStream.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I add events to this stream inside of actions:

```dart
  void navigateToNextScreen() {    
    _eventStream.sink.add('nav');
  }

  void openDialog() {    
    _eventStream.sink.add('dialog');
  }
```

In my UI widget I have:

```dart
  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    context.read<Transactions>().eventStream.listen((event) {
      if (event == 'nav') {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => SecondScreen(),
          ),
        );
      } else if (event == 'dialog') {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(content: Text("Meow")));
      }
    });    
  }
```

I used here `afterFirstLayout` lifecycle method from the `after_layout` package, which is just a wrapper for `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`

---

07.07.20 UPD.: Just found a package that can be used for event reactions:
https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus

It basically uses the same approach with StreamController under the hood.

Comment: @RémiRousselet what do you think? Is it a good solution or not?